# Exception when running a Java FXML project (Exception in Application start method)

Tags: java, exception, fxml

I'm absolutely new to FXML and its syntax, and because of that I've got to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm#CACFEHBI)
Oracle's tutorial on the topic doing some research.

I've done everything above figure 4-2 as it was specified (except the fact that I'm using Eclipse instead of NetBeans), but once I run the project, this is what I get on the console:

```
Exception in Application start method
```

while neither the stage nor its components appear.

Also, this window shows up:
[image]

I've done some research on the internet and I couldn't find information about this topic. There are questions about it on StackOverFlow, but the cause of the problem is not the same.

`FXMLTableView.java` (main method):

```
package application;

public class FXMLTableView extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Pane root = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_tableview.fxml"));

    primaryStage.setTitle("This is a title");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
    primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

`fxml_tableview.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10.0" vgap="10.0"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
    fx:controller="fxmltableview.FXMLTableViewController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
    </padding>
    <Label style="-fx-font: NORMAL 20 Tahoma;" text="Address Book"                
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
    </Label>
    <TableView fx:id="tableView" GridPane.columnIndex="0" 
        GridPane.rowIndex="1">
    </TableView>
</GridPane>
```

I don't that think it's necessary to show the `FXMLTableViewController`, since I don't have to use it yet and because of that it's practically empty, but just in case:

```
package application;

public class FXMLTableViewController {

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any additional information with the exception? Otherwise I suspect that the fxml file couldn't be found. Are you sure the given pathString is correct?

Comment: @n247s Every single file is in the same package, so for as far as I know, there should be no problems.
Now that you ask, there's a window that shows up too. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: it might be the same project, but if your xml file isnt in the 'resource' folder it won't find the file. Besides if the file is not directly placed in the resource folder, you'l need to give the complete path. (For example "myFXMLFilesFolder/fxml_tableview.fxml")

Comment: @n247s It seems strange that Oracle didn't mention that. I'll try typing the complete path.

Comment: Also on that error, you might wanna check this out: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/57630/

Comment: @n247s I just specified the entire path and it's exactly the same.
I'll try making the entire thing again. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I think I didnt explain it well enough, but you need the complete path from your resource folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**.

The problem was due to that I wasn't importing the libraries of each one of the classes I'm using on the FXML file.

This is how it has to be:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10.0" vgap="10.0"
   xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
   fx:controller="fxmltableview.FXMLTableViewController">
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
   </padding>
   <Label style="-fx-font: NORMAL 20 Tahoma;" text="Address Book"                
    GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
   </Label>
   <TableView fx:id="tableView" GridPane.columnIndex="0" 
       GridPane.rowIndex="1">
   </TableView>
</GridPane>
```

@n247s Thanks for the help.